# shell script - how to split a string with delimiter ","

Tags: php, shell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Split string based on delimiter in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/split-string-based-on-delimiter-in-bash)

i have a shell script which call by php and pass a variable ($1)

When i using `MYVAR = $1`, and `echo MYVAR` is not working

how can  i assign this variable (`$1`) to another variable and split it with delimiter "," and convert it into a array for looping?

Comment: it cant solve my problem "When i using MYVAR = $1, and echo MYVAR is not working"

Comment: Is that the literal notation in your script? Wouldn't that give you an error message?

Comment: it should be `MYVAR=$1` with no spaces anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, guessed answer in absence of code.

Variable assignments in shell scripts must be:

```
  MYVAR=$1
```

Spaces around are incorrect:

```
  MYVAR = $1
```

And the echo must output an actual variable, using the `$` prefix:

```
  echo $MYVAR
```

Not just the literal string:

```
  echo NOVAR
```